# Dropbox Chooser returns corrupted file

Tags: javascript, pdf, dropbox, dropbox-api, responsetext

posting here because I've not received a response over at the dropbox forums. [dropbox forum post](https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/204965035-Dropbox-Chooser-return-size-differs-from-responseText)

A few months ago I implemented the dropbox chooser and got everything working fine. Then about a week ago I ran into an issue where .pdf files would open, but contain blank pages and .docx files won't open at all (.rtf and .txt files open just fine)

Anyway I started digging and it turns out that the xhr.responseText that comes back is short a number of bytes (approximately 4% short in pdf files)

I've taken a look at the bytes and the beginning and end of file are correct (different versions have the same issue):

%PDF-1.5
...
%%EOF

Here's the relevant code:

```
var options = {
    success: function(files) 
    {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", files[0].link, false);
        xhr.responseType = 'arrayBuffer';
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(oEvent)
        {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200)
            {
                    var buffer = xhr.responseText;
                    console.log('File size: ' + files[0].bytes + 
                                ' | Buffer size: ' + buffer.length +
                                ' | Header size: ' + xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Length'));
            }
        }
        xhr.setRequestHeader("User-Agent", navigator.userAgent);
        try 
        {
            xhr.send(null);
        } 
        catch (err) 
        {
            alert(err);
        }
    },
    linkType: "direct", // or "preview"
    multiselect: false, // or true
};

Dropbox.choose(options);
```

In the console the "File size" and "Header size" values are the same, but the "Buffer size", the responseText, it smaller...

Why is dropbox returning all of the file contents?

Comment: On the Dropbox forum side, next time try posting in "API development." I've moved your post there. https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/204965035-Dropbox-Chooser-return-size-differs-from-responseText

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you're reading from the `XMLHttpRequest`'s `responseText` field instead of `response`. My guess would be that this results in (incorrectly) trying to interpret the data as text characters.

**EDIT:** You also need to change `arrayBuffer` to `arraybuffer` to actually get an `ArrayBuffer` back. Then you need to check the `byteLength` field to get the actual number of bytes contained in the `ArrayBuffer`.

Note that to use the `arraybuffer` response type, you'll need to switch to using an asynchronous `XMLHttpRequest`. (Drop the `false` last parameter to `xhr.open` or change its value to `true`.)

**EDIT2:**

A working (for me) example is at https://downloadtest.site44.com. The code is as follows:

```
Dropbox.choose({
    success: function (files) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', files[0].link);
        xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function (oEvent) {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                var buffer = xhr.response;
                console.log('File size: ' + files[0].bytes + 
                    ' | Buffer size: ' + buffer.byteLength + 
                    ' | Header size: ' + xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Length'));
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    },

    linkType: 'direct'
});
```

Comment: Changing to .response yields no difference

Comment: Your suggestions still don't fix the problem. Also, now the byte length comes back as undefined.

Comment: I've updated my answer with full working code, including a website where you can test it yourself. I tested in Chrome. If it's not working for you, please let us know which browser you're using.