# Parsing issue: Dropbox chooser with $.ajax works fine but not for .xlxs and .docx

Tags: ajax, parsing

Ecma scripting is not my strength so I was very happy to experience an instant success with Dropbox's file chooser. But ...

With files from Microsoft, I get a 200 but also a parser exception. It says that the content type is xml but cannot be parsed. I don not need any parsed content, I only need a String that contains some representation of the content. I hash it and keep its hash for later comparison.

So it is rather a parsing issue. Using smarx (that amazing guy is everywhere I stumble) [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32123876/dropbox-chooser-returns-corrupted-file) I have an ArrayBuffer from a XMLHttpRequest.

So my real question is: how do I convert an ArrayBuffer to a String with tolerant or no parsing.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes

Answer (score 0):

To unknown, why are you downvoting? Someone else may hit the same issue.

The challenge is to convert ArrayBuffer to a String. Renato shows how it can be done: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/06/How-to-convert-ArrayBuffer-to-and-from-String

Comment: I oversay https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754486/how-to-convert-arraybuffer-to-string